# Change where Java looks for javac.exe

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to upload my GAE app using the console in windows.  I am getting the error:

> cannot find javac executable based on java.home tried, "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javac.exe" and "C:\Program Files\Java\bi
>   n\javac.exe"
>
> Unable to upload app: cannot find javac executable based on java.home, tried "C:
>   \Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javac.exe" and "C:\Program Files\Java\bin\javac.exe

javac.exe is located in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\bin how do I tell java thats where it is

Comment: in the posted suggestions, save your JAVA_HOME variable surrounded by quotes java_home="c:\program files\java\jdk.1.6.0_18"

Comment: Perhaps you're using a script that sets JAVA_HOME to some misconfigured place before launching...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have two java versions installed?
From the information the sun jre and the Open jdk? The jre has no javac.exe and therefore cant find it.
Try to start your jar with C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\bin\java.exe instead of only java, if that doesn't help add the -Djava.home="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18" option to the call.

Answer (score 5):

You must set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to refer to the top-level folder where java is installed. Right-click "My Computer", Properties, Advanced, Environment Variables. If there's an existing JAVA_HOME variable, then correct it so that its value is

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18
```

If there is no existing variable, then create one by using the "New" button. It's up to you whether to do it for the current user or for the system.

Comment: I added both java.home and JAVA_HOME with C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18 and I am still getting the same error.  Could this value be kept somewhere else

Comment: see my answer below, it's possible whatever script you are running has it's own interpretation of "java.home" and does not use the environment variables

Answer (score 2):

The error message makes it clear that the lookup is based on `java.home`, have you tried adjusting that?

This output looks like it is coming from some sort of script which may have it's own definition of `java.home` which you need to change.

Comment: java.home # java/lang/System % getProperty &(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; <---That is in the jar file i am running the script from. Is it safe to change that line or should I change it somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution for this problem which I found is to use the `JAVA_HOME` variable in the script file.

This is the content of my bin\appcfg.cmd:

```
@"%JAVA_HOME%"\bin\java -cp "%~dp0\..\lib\appengine-tools-api.jar" com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg %*
```

Note: you should also check if JAVA_HOME points to an existing JDK

Answer (score 1):

The other way you can do set classpath variable using **set CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javac.exe\jdk1.6.0_18** in command prompt, but it works for single session.Everytime you need to set the variable.

Comment: so I should set java.home = classpath? or set java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javac.exe\jdk1.6.0_18.  Neither work.

Answer (score 0):

Set your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18`. Note that this variable points to the JDK location, not (unlike the `PATH` environment variable) to the path where the executables reside.